# Slowness in apache camel war deployment

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

hello we have an apache camel application where we have 7k + routes definition in camel xml.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <!-- Define the Camel context -->
    <camelContext id="api.service.v1.0.0" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" component="servlet" enableCORS="true" producerApiDoc="rest-v1.0.0-swagger.json">
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"/>
        </restConfiguration>
        <rest id="service.restlet" path="/v1.0.0" produces="application/json">
            <get id="id0" path="/test0">
                <to uri="direct-vm:testEndpoint0"/>
            </get>
            <get id="id1" path="/test1">
                <to uri="direct-vm:testEndpoint1"/>
            </get>
            ...
            <get id="id7000" path="/test7000">
                <to uri="direct-vm:testEndpoint7000"/>
            </get>
        </rest>
        <route id="direct-vm.testEndpoint1">
            <from uri="direct-vm:testEndpoint1"/>
            <setProperty name="type">
                <constant>testEndpoint1</constant>
            </setProperty>
            <process ref="testEndpointProcessor"/>
        </route>
        ...
        <route id="direct-vm.testEndpoint7000">
            <from uri="direct-vm:testEndpoint7000"/>
            <setProperty name="type">
                <constant>testEndpoint7000</constant>
            </setProperty>
            <process ref="testEndpointProcessor"/>
        </route>
        <bean id="testEndpointProcessor" class="com.test.ApiServiceProcessor"/>
    </camelContext>
```

All routes are all attached to single spring bean class as shown above.And we have spring contextLoaderListener to load the spring context.

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When we build this as war and deploy in an application server ( we use jboss), it takes around 10 minutes for deployment. One thing we observed is that if we remove the listener class from web.xml file it takes 10 to 20 seconds for deployment, but the rest service not works if we do so. Please can someone help to improve the deployment time.

Comment: This is not a common use case, so it is clearly not tested. Have you tried to use a profiler to identify the hot spots?